# Java and Metadata Exchange MEX

Tags: java, spring, wcf, wsdl

I'm trying to generate classes using an **MEX** endpoint unfortunately doesn't seems to be possible, because it won't find the **WSDL**.

I also want create a client for that web services using **spring** and **Apache CXF** but I don't know if I'm in the right path. I tried declaring the following on my **spring-config**:

```
<jaxws:client name="{http://payments.com:8080/}IOriginatorPaymentsService"
              createdFromAPI="true">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="ws-security.username" value="Username"/>
        <entry key="ws-security.password" value="Password"/>
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

My questions are: 
1. It's possible to generate the classes using only the following **MEX endpoint** `http://payments.com:8080/OriginatorPaymentsHNL/Service/OriginatorPaymentsService.svc/mex` the **WSDL** appears to be unexposed.

2. Could you provide an example of how to use spring and **Apache CXF** to create a client for the **MEX endpoint**.

As far I understand I can't unless the web service has enable the **httpGetEnabled** flag to expose the **WSDL**.

Thank you

Comment: I know this happen long time ago but the answer is that the provider of the service I was using have to enable httpGetEnabled flag to expose the WSDL as I state in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `httpGetEnabled` flag to expose the `WSDL`